# Update a specific array entry when index is unknown

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

On page load I receive an array of objects from the server, which are displayed using a `v-for` loop.

The application is real time, so when another user updates an object in the array, I receive a pusher event which contains the updated object (this is a Laravel 5.4 broadcast event containing the updated model).

How do I then locate that object within the array to replace it with the updated version?

Example component JS

```
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },

    mounted(){
       ...some code to get the array from the server

       this.items = server.response;
    },

    created() {
         Echo.private('channel-name)
           .listen('event', (event) => {

               **What do I do here with the received model to update the items array?**

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have some ID inside your `item` entity and then just lookup for the item with the same ID and replace it. Replacing can be done, for example, using map:

```
...
//assuming you have ID inside your item entity
//and your new "replacement" model is in event.item

.listen('event', (event) => {
  var newItem = event.item;

  this.items = this.items.map(item => {
   return item.ID === newItem.ID ? newItem : item;
  });
});
...
```

Comment: It appears that I was overthinking it. Thanks!